# I can't see my child theme custom gravatar in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am following the wordpress codex in creating a new gravatar. I can't see my new gravatar although I followed the instructions:

http://codex.wordpress.org/How_to_Use_Gravatars_in_WordPress

```
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'new_default_avatar' );

function new_default_avatar ( $avatar_defaults ) {
        //Set the URL where the image file for your avatar is located
        $new_avatar_url = get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/images/new_default_avatar.png';
        //Set the text that will appear to the right of your avatar in Settings>>Discussion
        $avatar_defaults[$new_avatar_url] = 'Your New Default Avatar';
        return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

Using inspect element, the avatar directory is: avatar_http://www.Domain.com/wp-content/themes/PARENT/images/gravatar.png

I can't get the function read it this way:
avatar_http://www.Domain.com/wp-content/themes/CHILD/images/gravatar.png

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
//Custom Child Gravatar
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'new_custom_default_gravatar' );

function new_custom_default_gravatar ($avatar_defaults) {
  $myavatar = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/new_default_avatar.png';
  $avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Your New Default Avatar";
  return $avatar_defaults;
}
```